# How to get local system IP that we get in ipconfig in cmd using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have used this below code for getting system local ip but not getting it,

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function callback(response)
    {
        
        console.log(response);
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=response.IPv4;
    }
    $.ajax({
        
    url:"https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/",
    dataType:"jsonp"
    })

</script
```

I also used this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
         var ip='<%=request.getRemoteHost()%>';
         document.getElementById('list1').innerHTML = ip;
         
         
         var ip1='<%=request.getRemoteAddr()%>';
         document.getElementById('list2').innerHTML = ip1;
         
         var ip2='<%=request.getLocalAddr()%>';
         document.getElementById('list3').innerHTML = ip2;
    
    </script> 



  I have also used the below code but I am not getting the IP that we get from inconfig from the command prompt
    
<script>  
$(document).ready(function ubsrt()
{
    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;  
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), 
    noop = function(){}; 
     
    pc.createDataChannel("");  
    pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);   
        pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){ 
    if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;

            var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];

            console.log('my IP: ', myIP); 
              $('.ipAdd').text(myIP);
          alert("IP: "+myIP);
            pc.onicecandidate = noop;
  
     }; 
});
</script>
```

I want the same IP  as ipconfig using javascript. I have used much code to find the IP but it is not the IP that I am getting from IPCONFIg

Comment: Try opening that site. There's some information to read ~ https://geoip-db.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil   I want the IP Address that we get from ipconfig from cmd using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
function callback(response) {
  console.log(response);
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = response.IPv4;
}

$.ajax({
  url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="data"></p>
```

Comment: I am using it in jsp how to use it

Comment: Maybe you have something blocking this script

Comment: In cmd, using ipconfig I am getting my IP as  '192.168.43.34'  but I am getting as '106.195.38.78' by using the above code...please help

Comment: I dont know if that is possible with plain javascript right now. It may be, but I'm currently stumped looking for an answer.

Comment: Is there any other way to get that IP that we can use in JSP